# TypeScript - Having a value satisfy one interface and one of two other interfaces

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Given the interfaces:

```
interface OperationHandler {
  IsCreatedByEvent(event: KeyboardEvent): boolean;
}

interface StatelessOperationHandler {
  GetStatelessOperation(): StatelessOperation;
}

interface StatefulOperationHandler {
  GetStatefulOperation(): React.ElementType;
}
```

I want to handle values that satisfy `OperationHandler` and either `StatelessOperationHandler` or `StatefulOperationHandler`. Then call `GetStatelessOperation()` if the value satisfies `StatelessOperationHandler` or call `StatefulOperationHandler()` if it satisfies `StatefulOperationHandler`.

Something like:

```
function fireOperationHandler(): void {
  const selectedHandler: OperationHandler = selectOperationHandler();
  if (selectedHandler satisfies StatefulOperationHandler) {
    selectedHandler.GetStatefulOperation();
    //more logic
  } else {
    //here can assume selectedHandler satisfies StatelessOperationHandler
    selectedHandler.GetStatelessOperation();
    //more logic
  }
}

function selectOperationHandler(): OperationHandler {
  // return a value that:
  // - satisfies OperationHandler
  // - satisfies either StatelessOperationHandler or StatefulOperationHandler
}
```

I've been trying various things with intersection and union types but not quite sure exactly how to do this. What kind of syntax or patterns would you use to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in TypeScript since the types are ignored when the TS code is converted into JavaScript code. Instead of using the interfaces, you either have to manually check if all keys are existing in the object or use classes, so you can use the instanceof method like this:

```js
let a = new A();
let b = new B();

let value: A | B = Math.random()>0.5 ? a : b; // choose a or b randomly

if(value instanceof A){
  // this object is instance of class A
} else if(value instanceof B){
  // this object is instance of class B
}
```

Depending on your use case, you can create wrapper classes that contain your object in the type of your interfaces, or completely store your data in class-based objects.